# How to rotate object to look mouse point in three js?

Tags: three.js, mesh

How to calculate object rotation.y in three js to look mouse pointer?
[image]

When i move mouse pointer from 1 to 2, arrow should turn to point 2. How do i calculate rotation.y?

Comment: Do you want the arrow to track your mouse pointer whilst it's moving?

Comment: @prisoner849 Yes. Arrow should point the mouse cursor direction!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an option, you can use `THREE.Raycaster()` with `THREE.Plane()` and use `.lookAt()` of your arrow to point it at the point of intersection of the raycaster's ray and plane.

Let's create our arrow object:

```
var coneGeom = new THREE.ConeGeometry(0.125, 1, 4);
coneGeom.translate(0, .5, 0);
coneGeom.rotateX(Math.PI / 2); // 
var coneMat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var cone = new THREE.Mesh(coneGeom, coneMat);
cone.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
scene.add(cone);
```

then we'll add an event listener for `mousemove`:

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", onmousemove, false);
```

and then our `onmousemove` function will be like this:

```
var plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), 0); // it's up to you how you will create THREE.Plane(), there are several methods
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); //for reuse
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();       //for reuse
var intersectPoint = new THREE.Vector3();//for reuse

function onmousemove(event) {
  //get mouse coordinates
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);//set raycaster
  raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, intersectPoint); // find the point of intersection
  cone.lookAt(intersectPoint); // face our arrow to this point
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/79n0ra6d/) example r86

Comment: can I ask you to take a look at my related question? I want to similarly rotate an arrow, but I want it to have a 3rd dimension if the mouse is close to the base of the arrow. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70918227/three-js-rotate-arrow-in-3d-to-track-mouse

Comment: Why does the coneGeom need to be rotated?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer To align it on Z-axis.