# Three JS - Access ArrowHelper direction?

Tags: three.js

Suppose I create an arrow helper, e.g. something like:

```js
const arrowPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
const arrowPosition = new THREE.Vector3(2, -2, 0);

arrowDirection.subVectors( scene.position, new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)).normalize();

arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper( arrowDirection, arrowPosition, arrowLength, 0xffff00, arrowHeadLength, arrowHeadWidth);
```

After creating it, how do I access its direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Three JS - Rotate arrow in 3D to track mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70918227/three-js-rotate-arrow-in-3d-to-track-mouse)

Comment: No, the answer on that page doesn't show how to access the arrow's direction after creating it.

Comment: You can write direction into helper's `.userData` to obtain it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, I'm not sure there is an easy way to access the direction, at least in a vector3 format. The value `dir` used in the `ArrowHelper` constructor (as described [in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/ArrowHelper.line)) is never assigned directly to a vector property of `ArrowHelper` or the `Object3D` parent class, but is instead used to set the quaternion property of the `ArrowHelper`, inherited from the parent class.

See the code snippet below from [the helper source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/helpers/ArrowHelper.js):

```js
setDirection(dir) {
  // dir is assumed to be normalized

  if (dir.y > 0.99999) {
    this.quaternion.set(0, 0, 0, 1);

  } else if (dir.y < - 0.99999) {
    this.quaternion.set(1, 0, 0, 0);

  } else {
    _axis.set(dir.z, 0, - dir.x).normalize();
    const radians = Math.acos(dir.y);
    this.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(_axis, radians);
  }
}
```

As listed in the Object3D docs, the `quaternion` describes the helper's rotation ([quaternion docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion)). A better discussion on the math might be found [on this unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/convert-quaternion-to-vector3.106789/), but to get the vector direction you'll need to use the `quaternion` field

Hope this helps and if someone can improve this explanation please do, my experience with Eulers and quaternions is limited